# Sphinxsearch Wordforms + Libstemmer

Tags: search-engine, sphinx, words

I'm currently working on Sphinx search engine and I have some issues with wordforms and libstemmer.
Here is my config:

```
wordforms = /etc/sphinxsearch/wordforms.txt

morphology = libstemmer_french, libstemmer_english 

http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2015/09/09/sphinx-2-2-10-release/
```

When libstemmer is activated, some associations in the wordforms file don't work at all. For example: girafe > giraffe, science > sciense, aztec > azteque, louie > louis, ...
When I disactivate libstemmer option, everything work fine.

So, I don't understand how to work with both libstemmer and wordforms since libstemmer is supposed to be called **after** wordforms, not **before**.

Answer (score 0):

> since libstemmer is supposed to be called after wordforms, not before.

It is applied after. BUT wordforms implement 'morphology exceptions' - ie if a word is changed by wordforms, then morphology is NOT applied. (only if no wordform subsitition is morphology applied)

---

About the only hope is this tidbit...

> Starting with version 2.1.1-beta, ..., if a line starts with a tilde ("~") the wordform will be applied after morphology, instead of before.

... so can put the libstemmed words into the wordforms, and then you get both sets of processing.

Comment: I tried to add a tilde in front of my examples, but the problem remains.